# Getting @html.hidden value

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I am trying to get the value from my variable.

```
@Html.Hidden("myVar", 0);
```

This variable will be updated according to the link that i clicked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".resend").click(function (){
            $('#myVar').val(this.id);
            console.log(document.getElementById('myVar').value);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This javascript will then call for the model to pop up.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!— Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to resend the registration link to the patient?</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href='@Url.Action("TherapistResendLinkToPatient", "Account", new { pid = I WANT TO CHANGE THIS TO THE VARIABLE #myVar })' style="text-decoration:none;">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm" />
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

i would like to change the pid = #myVar on my pop up box, however i do not know how can i insert the value. Any one have any clue how i can reference my pid to be #myVar?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to use #myVar that would be inserted into the generated url?

Comment: Hi. Actually value #myVar will be the value of the row i clicked on from my table. Apparently I have a list of data all with a href that will open up a pop up box. Hence if the user were to click on the 2nd row of the data, i wan to pass the information of 2nd row (patient id) to the pop up box so it will call the method TherapistResendLinkToPatient in my controller to resend an activation link

Comment: Right now, i know i can access the variable #myVar by typing document.getElementById('myVar').value, however i can't write this in the
@Url.Action("TherapistResendLinkToPatient", "Account", new { pid =(THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PUT THE VALUE}).

Comment: @Url.Action is RAZOR syntax, it is basically c#, That will be ran on the server before your javascript code executes on the client side. Are you looking to replace the Url.Action PID from the client side or the server side?

Comment: Please add the View that contains your `@Html.Hidden("myVar", 0);` in it's entirety, its difficult to see what you are trying to accomplish with the actions you have provided.

Comment: Yeah i want to replace the PID from the client side. Any idea how i can do it ?

Comment: the @Html.Hidden("myVar", 0); is just a variable that i declare so that i can store the information of the button i clicked. Hence i do not have any view on that.

Comment: What does the doctor do to initiate the bootstrap Modal?
It seems like you want the doctor to click a link/button that will initiate the bootstrap Modal and you want a link in the bootstrap Modal to be updated based on the button(patient) clicked on the original View.

Comment: The doctor will have to click on a link so that the doctor can resend a link to the respective patient. That is why i need the PID to be updated based on which patient the doctor wished to resend the link to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102789/discussion-between-chris-and-ugine).

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this the best way to insert the value is to every time the #myVar is changed is to update the `href` attribute, with [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to contain the new value of #myVar. An example of doing this is by in your `javascript` adding:

```
$('#confirmButton').attr('href','@Url.Action("TherapistResendLinkToPatient", "Account", new { pid = '+document.getElementById('myVar').value+' })');
```

You will also need to add a id to your a href wrapper around the button, like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("TherapistResendLinkToPatient", "Account", new { pid = '+document.getElementById('myVar').value+' })' style="text-decoration:none;" id="confirmButton">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm" />
</a>
```

I hope that helped

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. However the '+document.getElementById('myVar').value+' is giving me an error, apparently it is not written in the correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request the below should be able to help.

The Goal is to setup data in a data-target tag and then read that data when a button clicked. 
Your ASP.NET View page will need a forloop which I assume is already present as it creates a list of users from the DB. Below I assume a bit of data you can fill in the blanks.

MVC View Page.CSHTML

```
@model PROJECT.Models.PatientRESEND

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
   <th>Patient Name</th>
   <th>Patient Email</th>
   <th>Actions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
    <td>@item.FirstName</td>
    <td>@item.LastName</td>
    <td><button data-target="@item.PatientID|@item.FirstName @item.LastName" id="resend" class="resend">Send Link</button></td>
   </tr>
}
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Then use jQuery and Bootstrap to show information to the doctor.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resend").click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
          var patientid =  $(this).data("target").split('|')[0];
        var patientName =  $(this).data("target").split('|')[1];
        $("#myModal").find('.name').text(patientName);
        var resethref = $("#myModal").find('.resendLink').attr('href');
        resethref = resethref+patientid;
        $("#myModal").find('.pid_output').text("Link: "+resethref);
                    $("#myModal").find('.resendLink').attr("href", resethref);
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
});
```

---

```
 <td><button data-target="@item.PatientID|@item.FirstName @item.LastName" id="resend" class="resend">Send Link</button></td>
```

The above code has the Patient ID and Patient Name delimited by a | we then use jQuery to parse and update the DOM object of the bootstrap modal.

Please see the full working example at JSFiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/fcrvz0gk/

Answer (score 0):

My team managed to solve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableButton(b) {
        document.getElementById("cancel").disabled = true;
        b.disabled = true;
        b.form.submit();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".resend").click(function () {
            var id = this.id;
            $("#sendLink").attr('href', '/Account/TherapistResendLinkToPatient?pid=' + id);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Instead of storing a variable, we call for the method through Javascript.

Thanks for all your help, really appreciated it!

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. Though my script below is an advanced version of what you have done.